# Error:org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for application build with micronaut-bom1.2.10, graal19.2.1 & aws-sdk2.10.56

Tags: aws-sdk, micronaut, graalvm-native-image

Created an application using micronaut bom 1.2.10 version, along with software.amazon.awssdk:lambda:2.10.56 & software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.10.56 dependencies which had functionality to retrieve data from s3 storage and used graal 19.2.1 to create a native image.
The native image is successfully created but when i try to access the endpoint it fails for below exception:

```
failed: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

and series of exceptions with specifically while creating S3 client.
The exception also had failure at below point:

```
failed: Could not initialize class software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactoryjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory
```

Code for S3Client :

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().region(getRegion()).build();
```

build-native-image.sh

```
${GRAALVM_HOME}/bin/native-image --no-server -cp example-function-*-all.jar
-H:IncludeResources="git.properties"
-H:IncludeResources="logback.xml"
-H:IncludeResources="application.properties" \
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, when running tests, with the exact same NoClassDefFoundError but when using AWS sts and secretsmanager libraries. I could actually get it to work by just including the `jcl-over-slf4j` dependency, while the error happened when using the `slf4j-api` dependency. I did not need to exclude `commons-logging`. Snippet of dependency in maven `pom.xml` that worked:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.89</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

So this issue was resolved by adding below configuration in build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude(group = "commons-logging")
        }
    }
}
```

and in the dependencies added:
`compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: '1.7.30'`

I hope this helps.